# .each jQuery captures the last elements only in this form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a warning popup when a class named '.reqF' is not filled and send the form to action page when all the '.reqF' are filled..

This is my form

```
<form method="post" class="flat-p-form p-form-flat-extra5color4" action="/payment-verify-before-submit-multiple-students/" data-js-validate="true" data-js-highlight-state-msg="true" data-js-show-valid-msg="true" style="margin: 30px 0;" id="paymentForm" >

    <input type="text" name="parentName" placeholder="Parent Name" required class="form-control reqF" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="payee_email" placeholder="Email" required class="form-control reqF" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="parentMobile" placeholder="Mobile No" required class="form-control reqF" value=""/>
    <hr/>
    <input type="text" id="sudentname" name="sudentname[]" placeholder="Student Name" required class="form-control reqF" />
    <input type="text" id="admissionnmbr" name="admissionnmbr[]" placeholder="Admission No"  class="form-control reqF" required />
    <select id="budget" name="purpose[]" class="form-control reqF" required>
        <option class="p-select-default" value="">--Type--</option>
        <option value="SchoolFees">School Fees </option>
        <option value="BoardingFees">Boarding Fees</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" required class="form-control reqF inputChangeVal" data-js-input-type="number" />
    <select name="Grade[]" id="grade" class="form-control reqF" required>
        <option class="p-select-default" value="" >-- Grade --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>

    <div class="add_another_st"></div>
    <hr/>
  <button class="btn add_another_st_btn" style="float: right;">ADD ANOTHER STUDENT</button>
  <hr/>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        Total Amount
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="totalAmount" id="updatedTotalAmount" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: right; border: 0;" readonly />
    </div>
    <button class="btn" class="confirm" type="submit" name="confirm" id="payBtn"><i class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Pay Now</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Proccess Payment</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                    "Your about to make a online payment. Click 'Edit' to review the data before proceeding or click 'Continue' to confirm the details for payment."
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="continuebtn">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalforErrorMsg" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">All required fields should be filled.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                    "Following fields should be filled for all the students you've added"
                    <ul>
                        <li>Student Name</li>
                        <li>Admission No.</li>
                        <li>Grade</li>
                        <li>Payment Type</li>
                        <li>Amount</li>
                    </ul>
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">UPDATE</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = jQuery(".add_another_st"); //Fields wrapper section 3
        var add_button  = jQuery(".add_another_st_btn"); //Add button section 3

        var add_sec_3   = '<div class="add_another_st"><hr/><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group"><label for="sudentname" class="p-label-required">Student Name</label><span style="color: red"> Type the name as how it appears in the college registry</span><div class="input-group p-has-icon"><input type="text" id="sudentname" name="sudentname[]" placeholder="Student Name" class="form-control reqF" required aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"/><span class="input-group-state"><span class="p-position"><span class="p-text"><span class="p-required-text"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span></span></span></span><span class="p-field-cb"></span><span class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></div></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="name" class="p-label-required">Admission No</label><div class="input-group p-has-icon"><input type="text" id="admissionnmbr" name="admissionnmbr[]" placeholder="Admission No" class="form-control reqF" required /><span class="input-group-state"><span class="p-position"><span class="p-text"><span class="p-required-text"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span></span></span></span><span class="p-field-cb"></span><span class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i></span></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="budget" class="p-label-required">Payment Type</label><label class="input-group p-has-icon p-custom-arrow"><select id="budget" name="purpose[]" class="form-control reqF required"><option class="p-select-default" value="">--Select--</option><option value="SchoolFees">School Fees </option><option value="BoardingFees">Boarding Fees</option></select><span class="input-group-state"><span class="p-position"><span class="p-text"><span class="p-valid-text"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span class="p-error-text"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></span></span></span><span class="p-field-cb"></span><span class="p-select-arrow"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span><span class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></span></label></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="name" class="p-label-required">Amount <span style="color: red"> (Numbers only)</span></label><div class="input-group p-has-icon"><input type="text" id="amount" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control inputChangeVal reqF" data-js-input-type="number" required /><span class="input-group-state"><span class="p-position"><span class="p-text"><span class="p-required-text"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span></span></span></span><span class="p-field-cb"></span><span class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><p>Grade</p><label class="input-group p-custom-arrow"><select name="Grade[]" class="form-control reqF" required><option class="p-select-default" value="">-- Select --</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option></select><span class="input-group-state"><span class="p-position"><span class="p-text"><span class="p-required-text"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span></span></span></span><span class="p-field-cb"></span><span class="p-select-arrow"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></label></div></div></div><a href="#" class="remove_field btn" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">-</a></div>';

        // Add Brother begins

            var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var x = 1; //initlal text box count

            //jQuery(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            //jQuery(add_button).click(function(e){
            jQuery(add_button).on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment
                    jQuery(wrapper).append(add_sec_3); //add section
                    jQuery('.add_another_st .add_another_st:last').hide();
                    jQuery('.add_another_st .add_another_st:last').show('fast');
                }
            });

            jQuery(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                //e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).parent('div').slideUp(1000, function() {
                    jQuery(this).remove();
                    x--;
                    updateTotal();
                });
            });

        // Add Brother Ends

        function updateTotal()
        {
            var price = 0;

            jQuery(".inputChangeVal").each(function(){
                 var t = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val(), 10);
                 price = price + t;
            });

            //var total = (price + 1) * 1.05; 
            var total = price.toFixed(2);
            jQuery(".totalAmount").val(total);
            console.log('updateTotal Runs');
        }
        jQuery(document).on("change, keyup", ".inputChangeVal", updateTotal);

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#payBtn').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var empty = false;
                jQuery('.reqF').each(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() === '') {
                        console.log('error');
                        empty = false;
                    } else empty = true;
                });
                if (empty == true)
                    jQuery('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                else
                    //console.log('your error message');
                    jQuery('#myModalforErrorMsg').modal('toggle');
            });

            jQuery('#continuebtn').on('click', function() {
                jQuery('form').submit();
            });

            var hiddenTot = jQuery('.reqFamount').val() ;
            //alert (hiddenTot);
            jQuery(".totalAmount").val(hiddenTot);
        });

    });
    </script>
```

but the thing is it shows the `#myModalforErrorMsg` box only if the last element / grade is not filled up.

I am able to submit the form only after fill the `grade` and when I left other `.reqF` fields are empty..

why is that??

Sometimes it works on local host but never in WordPress..

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in this snippet

```
                jQuery('.reqF').each(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() === '') {
                        console.log('error');
                        empty = false;
                    } else empty = true;
                });
                if (empty == true)
                    jQuery('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                else
                    //console.log('your error message');
                    jQuery('#myModalforErrorMsg').modal('toggle');
```

Since, you are iterating through all elements, If last one is filled empty becomes true and hence error doesnt show. What you want is if any of the empty is false you show show error. 
You can modify if loop as below to make it work. Initialize empty as true.

```
                    if (jQuery(this).val() === '') {
                        console.log('error');
                        empty = empty && false;
                    } else empty = empty && true;
```